# Add a checkbox (or similar) to iPhone app using XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, interface, storyboard

I notice in Objects Library when I'm in editor, there are checkboxes. But they disappear when I go to the storyboard. So is there a way to add a chechbox in iPhone interface or are they meant for other platform? If it's not possible, is there something else that could do the same job? I'm making a search function and I want a criteria to be added in the search if the chechbox is checked, that's why I need something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkboxes are for OS X.  The iOS equivalents are switches.  If they aren't appropriate, you can roll your own checkbox using buttons.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought about using the switches, if could change the text inside it I could use them but. But that seems like more trouble than just making my own checkbox like this tutorials last button: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9yUcJJmCzo